# Controlling other app's volumes

Tags: iphone, ios, volume

I've got an app written to control my iPodMusicPlayer, but I want to be able to control the system's default music source (Pandora, Spotify, etc) as opposed to the iPod when they're playing. I can write the code to check if they're playing or not and respectively change the volumes, I just don't know how to access the default audio source/other app's audio.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can manipulate the system or other app volume. The best you can do is to display an alert asking the user to go to Settings & increase/decrease the volume. You cannot even launch the Settings app directly from your app.

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Nah, that's no good. I'm looking to control the volume automatically so I won't have to change it myself. But thanks for the suggestion.